# PHP MYSQL sort using price high to low using select box

Tags: php, sorting, button

I'm trying to add a sort button where i can i sort by price high to low, low to high, A to Z, most recent. I have the product.php and index.php file. currently i already have filter by category. The product.php file includes filters and I would to  also add sort filters.

Product.php

```
<?php 
$connection = mysqli_connect( 'localhost', 'root', '' );
if ( !$connection ) {
    die( 'Database Connection Failed' . mysqli_error( $connection ) );
}
$select_db = mysqli_select_db( $connection, 'test' );
if ( !$select_db ) {
    die( 'Database Selection Failed' . mysqli_error( $connection ) );
}
$query = 'SELECT * FROM test ';

$result = mysqli_query( $connection, $query );
$products = array();
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result, MYSQLI_ASSOC ) ) {
    array_push( $products, $row );
    $id=$row['id'];

}



// Filters
$cat_filter = isset($_GET['cats']) ? $_GET['cats'] : '';
$search_filter = isset($_GET['search']) ? $_GET['search'] : '';

// Default limit
$limit = isset($_GET['per-page']) ? $_GET['per-page'] : 3;

// Default offset
$offset = 0;
$current_page = 1;
if(isset($_GET['page-number'])) {
    $current_page = (int)$_GET['page-number'];
    $offset = ($current_page * $limit) - $limit;
}

// filter products array based on query
if(!empty($cat_filter) || !empty($search_filter)) {
    $filtered_products = array();
    foreach($products as $product) {
        if( !empty($cat_filter) && !empty($search_filter) ) {
            
            if( ( strpos($product['title'], $search_filter) !== false || $product['sku'] == $search_filter ) && $product['category'] == $cat_filter ) {
                $filtered_products[] = $product;
            }

        }
        else if(!empty($cat_filter) && $product['category'] == $cat_filter) {

            $filtered_products[] = $product;
        }
        else if(!empty($search_filter) && ( strpos($product['title'], $search_filter) !== false || $product['sku'] == $search_filter) ) {
            
            $filtered_products[] = $product;
        }
        
    }
    
    $products = $filtered_products;
}

$paged_products = array_slice($products, $offset, $limit);

$total_products = count($products);

// Get the total pages rounded up the nearest whole number
$total_pages = ceil( $total_products / $limit );

$paged = $total_products > count($paged_products) ? true : false;

if (count($paged_products)) {
    foreach ($paged_products as $product) { ?>
       
   <div class="col-md-4 product-wrapper">
           <div class="product">
               <div class="product-image">
                   <img src="<?php echo $product['image']; ?>" />
                </div>
                <div class="product-title">
                    <h3><?php echo $product['title']; ?></h3>
                </div>
                <div class="product-info">
                    <p class="product-sku"><?php echo $product['sku']; ?></p>
                    <p class="product-price">R <?php echo $product['price']; ?></p>
                    <p class="product-category">Listed in <?php echo $product['category']; ?></p>
                     <a href="properties-details.php?id=<?php echo $product['id'];*/?>" >View More</a>
                    
                </div>
           </div>
           
       </div>
-->
<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
      <div class="properties">
        <div class="image-holder"><img src="<?php echo $product['image']; ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="properties">
          <?php if($availablility == 0){ ?><div class="status sold">Available</div> <?php } else { ?>
          <div class="status new">Not Available</div>
          <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <h4 style="color: #333333"><a href="properties-details.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo $product['sku']; ?></a></h4>
        <i class="fa fa-map-marker" style="font-size:14px;color:red"></i> <span  style="font-style:italic;" class="price"><?php echo $address?></span>
          <p class="price" style="
    font-family: 'Poppins';
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 18px;" >Price: $<?php echo $pri; ?> </p>
          
         
       
        <label class="price"><?php echo substr($description,0,100); ?>....</p> 
        <div class="listing-detail">
        
                               <span class="flaticon-bed"></span><label class="price"> Beds: </label> <?php echo $bedroom; ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  &nbsp; 
                  <span class="flaticon-parking"></span><label class="price"> Garage: </label> <?php echo $garare; ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;  &nbsp; 
                          </p> 
                        <span class="flaticon-bath"></span><label class="price"> Baths: </label> <?php echo $bathroom; ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  &nbsp; 
                  <span class="flaticon-house"></span><label class="price"> Rooms: </label> <?php echo $rooms; ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;  &nbsp; 
          </p>
      
        
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="properties-details.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>">View Details</a>
          </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <?php } ?>
      <!-- properties -->


</div>
           
     <?php }
}

else {
    echo '<p class="alert alert-warning" >No results found.</p>';
}
 
 if ($paged) {
     require('pagination.php');
 }
```

index.php

```
  <div class="filters row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <form id="filter-form" class="form" action='index2.php' method="post">
                    <span>Filter Products</span>
                    
                    <select name="cats" class="form-control form-control-sm">
                        <option value="">Filter by Category</option>
                        <option value="eat">Eat</options>
                        <option value="drink">Drink</options>
                        <option value="Pants">Pants</options>
                        <option value="Shirts">Shirts</options>
                    </select>
                    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search" class="form-control form-control-sm" title="Search by product name or SKU" />
                    
                    <span> Show </span>
                    <select name="per-page" class="form-control form-control-sm">
                        <option value="3">3</options>
                        <option value="6">6</options>
                        <option value="9">9</options>
                        <option value="12">12</options>
                    </select>
                    
                    <input type="submit" value="Filter" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="all-products" class="row all-products">
 
           <?php require('resources/products.php'); ?>
```

Comment: Instead of fetching all records from the database and filter them out using PHP after, put the filtering and sorting into the database query so you only get the necessary records already sorted from the database. The same goes with the pagination.

Comment: I would like the customer to sort for themselves - High to Low , Low to High , A to Z , Z to A , Most Recent

Comment: I understand, but that doesn't negate the first comment. You can sort the result based on the user input in the query as well.

Comment: Why are you nesting `if( !empty($cat_filter) && !empty($search_filter) ) {` inside of `if( !empty($cat_filter) && !empty($search_filter) ) {`? Why are you counting before entering a `foreach()`? What ordering do you actually need? Why not order in sql? `elseif` should be one word in php.  Please teach yourself what the null coalescing operator does.

Comment: I need a sort By button , which has Price Low to High , Hight to Low , A to Z , Z to A , Most Recent.  This is for filtering part which is working - Why are you nesting if( !empty($cat_filter) && !empty($search_filter) ) { inside of if( !empty($cat_filter) && !empty($search_filter) ) {? Why are you counting before entering a foreach()